# How to get username of logged-in user when application started with RUNAS

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I use to start Excel/MS Access with a short RUNAS script:
`runas /netonly /user:%id% "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c START excel.exe /r"`

Now my question: how could I get the logged-in username for this application(!) in VBA (xls, accdb)? Is there a way?

Comment: You can try `Environ("Username")` (not sure if this is affected by runas).

Comment: @Andre: It is not. It will return the username of the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```vb
RunAs /netonly /user:%id% "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c START MSACCESS.exe """d:\Path\Your Database Name.accdb""" /cmd %id%"
```

Then, in VBA, read the value with `Command`:

```vb
id = VBA.Command
```

Comment: Wow, working! The only thing is that I'm not able to start the local accdb file.

Comment: It is _Access_ that should start - using your accdb file. So, what is "working"?

Comment: Only the application is starting, but on "vanilla", not the file itself. In the access screen I've to pick the local file to open it. 
I mean, the `d:\Path\YourDatabase.accdb` part of the string above is not working.

Comment: Perhaps your filename has spaces. Then quotes are needed. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Now working like a charm, Thanks a lot Gustav!